# Add a nested function to a function body dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nested, nested-function

In JavaScript it's possible to have functions in functions.

```
function cow() {
  function moo() {
    console.log("moo");
  }
  moo();
}
cow();
```

Is it possible to dynamically add the nested function? Something like this?

```
function cow() {
  moo();
}

cow.moo = function () {
  console.log("moo1");
};

cow();
```

Comment: yes, I think so. Try removing `moo();` from `cow`, and create the new cow with `bob = new cow()`. You can then call moo on `bob`, using `bob.moo()`.

Comment: nope. What are you trying to do?

Comment: it's not the same. In the second case you add a property `moo`  that is a function to an object `cow`. Functions are objects in JavaScript.

Comment: @evolutionxbox None of the two code blocks will make this work. The first code block creates a function `moo` scoped to the function `cow`. The second code block creates a “static” function as a property of `cow`. None of these will create an instance method on `cow.prototype`.

Comment: You could create a curried function like `const outer = (func) => () => func(), inner = outer(() => console.log("moo")); inner();`, but without more context, there’s no way to tell if this is applicable here.

Comment: I should take a break... I tried.

Comment: Everything in javascript is very dynamic. So I'm just curious if it's possible. But my guess is that it's not. Couldn't find anything relevant when googling.

Comment: @Arlukin Local scope is not dynamic (since the deprecation of the `with` statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you ask "is it possible", then the answer is sadly yes:

```
  function cow(fn) {
    let see = "oh no";
    eval(fn.toString())();
 }

 cow(function moo() {
   console.log(see);
 });
```

But except for this hack, it isn't really possible, because JavaScript has *lexical scoping*, which means that only the position in the source code determines which variables a function can access. You cannot change the position in the source code (except you dynamically evaluate strings as code, which you should not).

If it is just about *calling* some function dynamically, without accessing variables from the outer function, then you can just pass a function as a parameter (which is actually quite usual in JavaScript):

```
  function cow(moo) {
     moo();
  }

 cow(function mooo() {
   console.log("mooo");
 });
```

For sure you could then also pass arguments into the `moo()` call and receive them in the `mooo` function (or any other function).